# Именование областей видимости при использовании паттерна "Модуль"

Tags: javascript, node.js, шаблоны-проектирования, терминология

В Node.js имплементирован паттерн "модуль"

```
// ???
var fs = require('fs')

// ????    
var XXX = function(...) {...}

module.exports.init = function( db ) {
    // Private member
    var YYY = function (...) {...}

    // Public member
    mod.ZZZ = function (...) {...}
    return mod
}
```

Возникла проблема в терминологии, как правильно именовать "область видимости" *XXX*, *YYY*, и *ZZZ*:

- *XXX* - эта фунцкия видна *YYY*, *ZZZ* и доступна для DI извне (rewire).
- *YYY* - эта фунция видна только внутри *init*. Самая узкая область.
- *ZZZ* - публичный метод/фунцкия (public method/function)

Comment: Это попытка перевести какую-то статью? Немного сложно без контекста понять что требуется от терминологии.

Comment: нет, это попытка дать названия терминам для упрощения коммуникации

Comment: Ну по-хорошему таких спец терминов нет. По сути отличают переменные видимые в пределах функции и глобальные. А тот факт что где-то ссылки сохраняются благодаря механизму замыканий это не создает отдельного типа области видимости. Я правильно вопрос понял?

Comment: `function scope`, `module scope` `public scope` - не?

Comment: в текущем стандарте JS модули это хак, типа обертки кода в замыкания. Если это не смущает, и не интересует как устроен язык, то можно выбрать любые удобные термины.

Comment: Возможно эта информация будет полезной - [книжка](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/ch04.html).